# Delete files and folder useing FileSystemObject from network Path

Tags: vb6

I wanna delete some files and folders using FileSystemObject in an application who run from another machin. i have done anything but it warns me: permission denied

Answer (score 2):

If the permissions are set to stop you deleting files, then there is nothing you can do except change the permissions both on the file system and the share itself.

One they've been changed, you can work with any files using the UNC path in both the FSO and the native VB methods (preferred).

Comment: To be clear, the FSO works with local and LAN files, folders, and drives.  Even then the LAN shares must exist or there is no UNC path to work with.  I'm excluding the backdoor "administrative shares" because I'd hope everyone has those locked down, which they ought to be by default after Win2K.

Comment: Oops, I left out WebDAV shares as another possiblity, but that also requires that the remote system makes an effort to expose them.

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, please accept it by clicking on the check mark next to my post. Thanks